# Display images from url using json-android

Tags: android, json

AsyncTask of EventHome.java

```
class LoadProfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EventHome.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Profile JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        String json = null;
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(PROFILE_URL);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            json = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

            Log.i("All Events: ", json.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        super.onPostExecute(json);
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try{
        event_all = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray user = event_all.getJSONArray("events");
        JSONObject jb= user.getJSONObject(0);
        String name = jb.getString("name");
        String venue=jb.getString("location");
        String date=jb.getString("date_d");
        String descr=jb.getString("descr");
        String image1=jb.getString("images1");

        // displaying all data in textview

        tv3.setText(name);
        tv4.setText(venue+", "+date);
        tv5.setText(descr);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

json output string

```
{"events":[{"id":"1","name":"Demo Event","descr":"This is a demo","date_d":"12\/27\/2014","time_t":"","images":"http:\/\/www.adagioinfotech.com\/event\/uploads\/event\/demo.png","images1":"http:\/\/www.adagioinfotech.com\/event\/uploads\/event\/demo1.png","location":"Ernakulam","publish":"1"},{"id":"2","name":"Flower Show","descr":"xfvslkdfvsw fvgersdgvel fgvmerlkgjer fgertgkjerltgf dfrgergt","date_d":"12\/29\/2014","time_t":"","images":"http:\/\/www.adagioinfotech.com\/event\/uploads\/event\/demo.png","images1":"http:\/\/www.adagioinfotech.com\/event\/uploads\/event\/demo1.png","location":"Thodupuzha","publish":"1"},{"id":"3","name":"Cultural Event","descr":"sfsdnfkjn sdfrelegkrg fdgvlkgvjmer fdgbelkrek dferlkgelrk dfgerge","date_d":"12\/30\/2014","time_t":"","images":"http:\/\/www.adagioinfotech.com\/event\/uploads\/event\/demo.png","images1":"http:\/\/www.adagioinfotech.com\/event\/uploads\/event\/demo1.png","location":"Idukki","publish":"1"}]}
```

I want to display the images from the json values. How can i do that.

Comment: use `Picasso` for loading those images in `ImageView`

Comment: Picasso.with(this).load(image1).into(iv7); //the method with(context)in type picasso is not applicable for the arguments (EventHome.LoadProfile)

Comment: what is `EventHome` ? is it `Activity` name

Comment: check my answer tell me if you faced any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load image using [`picasso`](http://square.github.io/picasso/) like this

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
   super.onPostExecute(json);
   // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
   pDialog.dismiss();
   try{
        event_all = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray user = event_all.getJSONArray("events");
        JSONObject jb= user.getJSONObject(0);
        String name = jb.getString("name");
        String venue=jb.getString("location");
        String date=jb.getString("date_d");
        String descr=jb.getString("descr");
        String image1=jb.getString("images1");

        // displaying all data in textview

        tv3.setText(name);
        tv4.setText(venue+", "+date);
        tv5.setText(descr);
        if(image1 != null && !image1.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
              Picasso.with(EventHome.this).load(image1).into(iv7);
     }catch(Exception e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
```

Place picasso jar in `libs` folder of your project or add it to your dependencies in your build.gradle file (see the [Picasso site](http://square.github.io/picasso/))

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void onPostExecute(String json) { .....

ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
.cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
.showImageForEmptyUri(fallback)
.showImageOnFail(fallback)
.showImageOnLoading(fallback).build();

//initialize image view
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)

//download and display image from url
imageLoader.displayImage(image1, imageView, options);
```